# is it possible to put a WCF Router service infront of a RIA Service

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, wcf, wcf-ria-services

We would like to protect the database and not have connections to it in the DMZ, it is possible to to use the new WCF Router services to redirect to RIA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but a better and easier solution would be to use ARR. see [Making WCF Ria Services work in a DMZ](http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/post/Making-WCF-RIA-Services-work-in-a-DMZMultitier-architecture-using-Application-Request-Routing.aspx)